# Retain the 1 row with certain string value and drop the rows if same ID has other multiple values in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I wanted to find the rows that have multiple values based on the ID and retain the rows that say "Yes" and delete the rest.

My table looks like

```
ID.  value
1.   Yes
1.   No
2.   Yes
2.   No
3.   Yes
4.   Yes
3.   No
```

Identify the duplicates and delete the values that say "No"

Expected output

```
ID  value
1.  Yes
2.  Yes
3.  Yes
4.  Yes
```

NOTE: I want to delete the rows with "No" only if the ID is duplicated

Comment: are you ok with pyspark?

Comment: No, I writing my script in pandas. this is part of the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep='first'` arg:

```
df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='first')

    ID value
0  1.0   Yes
2  2.0   Yes
4  3.0   Yes
5  4.0   Yes
```

Another option is to remove the `No` before then drop the duplicates:

```
df.query("ID != 'No'").drop_duplicates('ID', keep='first')
```

Comment: what does keep = first does? How does it know Yes comes first? What if No comes in the first place

Comment: once they find duplicate process will take first record and ignore another one.

Comment: My question is, what happens when No comes first and Yes comes behind?

Comment: No will never come because we are getting only Yes value right by doing df.query("ID != 'No'")

Comment: @Yash can you update your question with a use case where this solution would fail ? I'd be happy to modify to accordingly/

Comment: I am fascinated how this is able to return correct output when `ID` column is actually number, but you compare it against `No`. I am kind of surprised OP accepted this answer as is :)

Comment: In my case ID is not a number its a string

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using below line

```
df = df.query("ID != 'No'").drop_duplicates('ID', keep='first')
```